# How to update nested values with immutable.js

Tags: immutable.js

I have a structure like this one:

```
{
  members: [
    { memberId: 1, workspaces: [123, 124] },
    { memberId: 2, workspaces: [124] },
    ...
    ]
}
```

How could I update the workspace list for one member with Immutable.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found!

```
members.updateIn(
  ['0', 'workspaces'],
  (workspaces) => workspaces.push(125)
)
```